# what is the usage of HTML5 figure with img

Tags: html, image, tags, figure, difference

Is there any specific advantage/usage of using HTML5 [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/figure) over [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)?

I think `<figure>` is useless without [`<figurecaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/figcaption), isn't it?

It will be helpful if explain with an example.

Comment: related http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-consider-wrapping-your-code-with-a-figure-element--cms-21646

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Images are not technically inserted into an HTML page, images are linked to HTML pages. The `<img>` tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.

While the content of the `<figure>` element is related to the main flow, its position is independent of the main flow, and if removed it should not affect the flow of the document

From http://dev.w3.org/

"[The img element represents an image](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html)," while "[t]he figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting [the document’s meaning.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figure.html)"

Comment: Sorry but really did not get you. will you explain with any example?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя: the last (long) link is dead and I can't even get to its [parent](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/) :-(

Answer (score 10):

> The  tag provides a **container** for content that is
>   equivalent to a figure or diagram in a book. ***It can be used to
>   group a caption with one or more images, a block of code or other
>   content***.

In other words,  enables us to work more freely, realistically with images, diagrams by enabling to group them & caption one or images with a single caption.

Source: http://www.html-5.com/tags/figure-tag/index.html

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 `figure` is used whenever you use `img, video` tag with `caption (figcaption)` on it

If you have a number of related images (or other content) with caption text,  you can use nested figure elements to associate both a group caption and an individual caption to each  instance using the `figcaption` element.

```
<figure role="group">
 <img src="castle-etching.jpg" alt="The castle has one tower, and a tall wall around it.">
 <figcaption>Charcoal on wood. Anonymous, circa 1423.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

[**Here are some examples**](http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/figures-nested.html)

Comment: @diEcho I can not right a full page post here :) Read figure in web pages: http://www.sitepoint.com/real-world-accessibility-html5-aria-and-the-modern-web/

Comment: Not correct, the figure is only used in some cases: Cases where its content can be deleted without affecting the main flow and when its position can be placed independently from that of the main content.
Putting all your images in a <figure> tag is a bad habit.